pandasのcombine_firstメソッドで警告の発生を抑止する方法
pd.Seriesのcombine_firstメソッドを呼び出したら、FutureWarningの警告が発生しました。
全レコードが欠損値の場合に発生するようですが、どのように警告の発生を抑止するべきでしょうか？
combine_firstメソッドを実行する前に、
元のデータフレームのデータの欠損値チェックをしなければならないものなのでしょうか？
import pandas as pd
print('Pandas version:', pd.__version__)

print('- 元のDataFrame')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        {'price': None},
        {'price': None}
    ],
    index=pd.Index(['0001', '0002'], name='id')
)
display(df)

print('- 更新するデータ')
series = pd.Series(
    data=[50, 60],
    index=pd.Index(['0001', '0002'], name='id'),
    name='price'
)
display(series.to_frame())

df['price'] = df['price'].combine_first(series)
display(df)


◇実行結果

◇警告メッセージ
/tmp/ipykernel_206857/783509915.py:27: FutureWarning: The behavior of array concatenation with empty entries is deprecated. In a future version, this will no longer exclude empty items when determining the result dtype. To retain the old behavior, exclude the empty entries before the concat operation.
  df['price'] = df['price'].combine_first(series)



もしかするとこれと類似(どちらのDataFrameにNoneがあるかが逆ですが)かもしれませんね。BUG: combine_first raise FutureWarning surprisingly #58304 なのでもしかすると次？のv3.0.0で解決するかもしれません。

ありがとうございます。警告なので直接的な支障ないので修正されるのを待ちます。

ちなみに FutureWarning を抑止する解説の記事はこちら。PandasのFutureWarningを抑制する方法
